# How to check _findenv SIGSEGV Error in qnx?

Tags: segmentation-fault, qnx

I'm newbie for qnx application development.
(One process is main application what included in two dynamic library like a.so, b.so)

I have this error for application, but i don't know what to do.

So, could someone help me about this error how to check and how to fix it..

I guess it's related to dynamic library.

Thank you.

Error Message when application stopped.

"Process 184343 ("App") terminated SIGSEGV code=1 fltno=11 ip=01032174(/usr/lib/ldqnx.so.2@_findenv+0x14c) mapaddr=00032174. ref=00000298
"

I also thought _findenv() is fault but, I didn't use environment variable function in my application like setenv(), getenv(), putenv().

So, I focused on SIGSEGV. Application is quiet huge, I can't show small example here.

App is based on ethernet communication. And then transfer data to other board by using SPI(Serial Communication).

Could you let me know what function call __findenv() in linux, qnx, unix etc...

I don't know how to find keyword to resolve this problem.

Comment: I don't understand why you are focused on memcpy().  Your program crashes in _findenv(), which is a pretty stable function used in lots of contexts.  I think it is fair to say that if _findenv() is faulting; it is either because its arguments are invalid, or that the environment space has become corrupt.   Perhaps you could post some relevant code -- that is a small example which compiles.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I also thought _findenv() is fault but, I didn't use environment variable function in my application like setenv(), getenv(), putenv(). So, I focused on SIGSEGV.